# I want data from two older comps transferred/merged onto my new M2 Max under one user

Tags: time-machine, migration, migration-assistant

I just used Migration Asst. to transfer from my older Macbook Pro (Late 2013) to my new 16" M2 Max. All good. Now I want to transfer (ADD) the data from a Time Machine backup of a Macbook Pro M1 I recently returned to Apple (it had issues).

Here's where clarity is a rarity: can I do this and **NOT** *replace* but rather *merge* with the data already now transferred to the M2 Max. I have passwords, notes, voice memos, texts, and emails, etc., on both comps that cannot be dragged over (so I'm told), as well as sound libraries and installs of plug-in suites and Logic recordings that I want in one user on my new M2

Comment: How long did you have the M1 for? Did you not transfer the 2013 Mac's contents to that?

Comment: Simply said: Migration Assistant migrates, it does not merge. And if you think it through, a merge operation is nearly impossible in this case because there will be conflicts where the system can't decide which information to keep.

Answer (score 1):

> I have passwords, notes, voice memos, texts, and emails, etc., on both
> comps that cannot be dragged over (so I'm told), as well as sound
> libraries and installs of plug-in suites and Logic recordings that I
> want in one user on my new M2;

I suspect that this is going to be quite difficult from a TM backup, rather than directly from another Mac.

First the easy bit: Logic files are usually stored in ~/Music/Logic. You should be able to just copy the files over directly. Voice Memos are usually stored in the iTunes library, in a Voice Memos folder.

Email should get synced from the IMAP server, assuming you're using the same email accounts on both Macs.

Sound Libraries and plug-ins: I would suggest it's best if you just download the installers, as there's likely all kinds of files and configurations in all sorts of places.

Passwords and Notes: These are normally synced over iCloud. Are these not in iCloud?

For some things, it might be easiest to set up a temporary user account and migrate the data into that, where you can then access it and export it.